# laravel + vue router cannot get parameters from url

Tags: laravel-5, vue-router

I try to get parameters from url

let's say url contains:

```
localhost:8000/blog?q=hello
```

I want to grab `hello` to trigger function call

What I had declare in app.js in laravel webpack:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: []
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
});

export default app;
```

In blog page, I try to extract the parameter from url

```
new Vue ({
       el: "#blog-content",
   },

   mounted: function() {
       q = this.$route.query.q
       console.log(q)
   }
)
```

I `npm run dev` to compile and run the blog page it show error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

what is wrong? I am sure that Vue Router is properly installed in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the blog page that you use is not correct.

You recreate another Vue instance and in that case that new instance doesn't have a router passed to it. So I think that's why `this.$router` is undefined.

Also you don't pass the view Component to your router so it doesn't know what to look for with the specific url.

Here's your `app.js` file corrected

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Blog from './views/Blog';

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/blog',
            name: 'blog',
            component: Blog
        },
    ]
});
```

The blog view page template : `views/Blog.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
         My blog page
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                myvariable : ''
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            let q = this.$route.query.q;
            console.log(q);
        },
    };
</script>
```

Now it should works correctly :)

Edit : Also you don't need to export the `app` variable in your `app.js`

Remove the following line `export default app;` at the end of the file